# JQuery not working for container with 100vh

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I'm trying to make my entire container(`mainContainer`, containing a 100vh full screen video and a text overlay) to the left using a click on a div class(`next` `hvr-forward`) using jquery.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lo7xto2t/6/

```
$('.next').click(function() {$('.mainContainer').animate({"margin-right": '-=200'});});
```

Used the code above but its not working. Have tested it with css:borders so it is not a jquery problem.

HTML:

```
<div class = "mainContainer">
    <video poster ="poster.png" autoplay loop>
        <source src ="images/video.mp4" type ="video/mp4">
        <source src ="video.webm" type ="video/webm">   
    </video>
    <div class = "overlayAll">
        <div class = "text"> 
            We are BLXCK Co.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
video {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: 1;
background: transparent;
background-size: cover;
}
.mainContainer{
height: 100vh;
position: absolute;
opacity: 1;
}
.overlayAll {
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;    
height: 120vh;
}
.text {
position: fixed;
max-width: 50vw;
min-width: 50vw;
top: 30vh;
bottom: 30vh;
left: 15vw;
color: white;
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12vw;
display: flex;
line-height: 0.8em;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

Also have used Inspector but it seems my `mainContainer` is not moving. Are there any other ways to move the entire container to the left upon a mouse click like a slider?

Comment: Define *"not working"*. That is a virtually meaningless problem statement

Comment: I believe your property names for the animate function should not be in these `"` quotes

Comment: @charlietfl Nothing is happening even though I've called the function.

Comment: @Evochrome Have tried changing them but it's still not working. I believe my container is unable to move.

Comment: @Evochrome quote type is irrelevant for object properties

Comment: create a **runnable** demo that reproduces problem

Comment: Unsure if it is OK to post my entire code here as I'm getting alittle desperate as I've been stuck for 2 hours. :/

Comment: Do it in jsfiddle or other sandbox site like plunker,jsBin, codepen etc. Just enough to reproduce problem as per [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl https://jsfiddle.net/Lo7xto2t/ this is the jsfiddle! I think it's really hard to reproduce because there are so many elements within my mainContainer. But thank you for all your help!

Comment: The class you want to animate doesn't even exist in demo. Also didn't include jQuery.js. Open browser console and check errors

Comment: @charlietfl My bad! I edited it and hopefully it's better.

Comment: @charlietfl did not know the links change after updating! https://jsfiddle.net/Lo7xto2t/6/

Comment: @charlietfl you're right, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would not animate because of the `fixed` property you gave to the `video` and `.text` elements.

Changing the mainContainer to `relative` and the sub elements to `absolute` (and some other small things, which you can see in the snippet), it works.

Hope it helps!

```js
$('.next').click(function() {
 $('.mainContainer').animate({
    right: '+=100vw'
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  background: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
}
.mainContainer{
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlayAll {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;    
  height: 100vh;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 50vw;
  min-width: 50vw;
  top: 30vh;
  bottom: 30vh;
  left: 15vw;
  color: white;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12vw;
  display: flex;
  line-height: 0.8em;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "mainContainer">
    <video poster ="poster.png" autoplay loop>
        <source src ="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type ="video/mp4">
        <source src ="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm" type ="video/webm">   
    </video>
    <div class = "overlayAll">
        <div class = "text next"> 
            We are BLXCK Co.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Evochrome!!!! It works! So it was about the positioning :/
I'm still new to this! Thank you so much for your help!